# How to hook BeginRequest and EndRequest in JavaEE?

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, page-lifecycle, java-ee-8

## Short Version

In JavaEE, i want to know when:

- when a request starts
- and when a request ends

and be able to inspect the request and response objects.

## Long Version

In the ASP.net world, if you want to know when a request starts and ends, you write an **`IHttpModule`**:

```
public class ExampleModuleForThisQuestion : IHttpModule
{
}
```

And then register your *"module"* in the web xml configuration file:

**web.config**:

```
    <system.webServer>
        <modules>
            <add name="DoesntMatter" type="ExampleModuleForThisQuestion "/>
        </modules>
    </system.webServer>
```

Inside your module you can register callback handlers for:

- **BeginRequest** event
- **EndRequest** event

The web-server infrastructure then calls you **`Init`** method. That is your opportunity to register that you want to receive notifications when a request starts, and when a request ends:

```
public class ExampleModuleForThisQuestion : IHttpModule
{
   public void Init(HttpApplication application)
   {
      application.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(beginRequest); //register the "BeginRequet" event
      application.EndRequest += new EventHandler(endRequest); //register the "EndRequest" event
   }
}
```

And now we have our callbacks when a *request starts*:

```
private void beginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)sender;

   //Record the time the request started
   application.Context.Items["RequestStartTime"] = DateTime.Now;

   //We can even access the Request and Response objects
   application.ContenxtLog(application.Context.Request.Headers["User-Agent"]);
}
```

and we have our callback when a *request ends*:

```
private void endRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)sender;

   //We can even access the Request and Response objects

   //Get the response status code (e.g. 418 I'm a teapot)
   int statusCode = application.Context.Response.StatusCode;

   //Get the request method (e.g. GET, POST, BREW)
   String method = application.context.Request.RequestType;

   //Get the path from the request (e.g. /ViewCustomer)
   String path = application.context.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath'
   
   //Get when the request started - that we recorded during "Begin Request"
   DateTime requestStartTime = (DateTime)application.Context.Items["RequestStartTime"];

   //And we can modify the response
   if ((DateTime.Now - requestStartTime).TotalSeconds = 17)
       application.Context.Response.StatusCode = 451;
}
```

## Now how to do it in JavaEE?

The question is: what is the moral equivalent of `IHttpModule` in the Java web-server world?

[Some people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29069662/how-to-get-request-object-from-httpsessionattributelistener) say that it is an [`ServletRequestListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequestListener.html):

> Interface for receiving notification events about requests coming into and going out of scope of a web application.
>
> A ServletRequest is defined as coming into scope of a web application when it is about to enter the first servlet or filter of the web application, and as going out of scope as it exits the last servlet or the first filter in the chain.

[Others insist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3663608/12597) that you want a *"filter"* and a *"filter chain"*.

Some say that a *"filter"* gives you everything that `ServletRequestListener` does, but that a *filter* can also be configured to run for only certain URL.

[This](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnafi.html) random page on docs.oracle.com says nothing about *"filters"*, and instead i need a `ServletContextListener`, because that's the only way to receive a notification for **each** request. But then they have a table that seems to contradict that, and that i want a `ServletRequestEvent`:

| Object | Event | Listener Interface and Event Class |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Web context | Initialization and destruction | `javax.servlet.ServletContextListener` and `ServletContextEvent` |
| Web context | Attribute added, removed, or replaced | `javax.servlet.ServletContextAttributeListener` and `ServletContextAttributeEvent` |
| Session | Creation, invalidation, activation, passivation, and timeout | `javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener`, `javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionActivationListener`, and `HttpSessionEvent` |
| Session | Attribute added, removed, or replaced | `javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionAttributeListener` and `HttpSessionBindingEvent` |
| Request | A servlet request has started being processed by web components | `javax.servlet.ServletRequestListener` and `ServletRequestEvent` |
| Request | Attribute added, removed, or replaced | `javax.servlet.ServletRequestAttributeListener` and `ServletRequestAttributeEvent` |

I don't know what any of these things are. I just want to be notified during a web-request:

- when the request processing begins
- when the request processing ends

## Writing Java code blind

I can try to transcribe the ASP.net code into Java-esque code on the fly, and hopefully someone can just fix it.

First we'll create a class that implements...`ServletRequestListener`?:

```
public class ExampleListenerForThisQuestion 
      implements javax.servlet.ServletRequestListener {

}
```

And then we register our *"module"* in our web xml configuration file:

**web.xml**

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>ExampleListenerForThisQuestion</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Now we will implement the [**requestInitialized**](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequestListener.html#requestInitialized(javax.servlet.ServletRequestEvent)) method to create our event listeners:

```
public class ExampleListenerForThisQuestion 
      implements javax.servlet.ServletRequestListener {

   public void requestInitialized(ServletRequestEvent sre) {
      //...now i'm stuck 
   }
}
```

That didn't get very var.

The closest question on stackoverflow to what i want is:

> [Event like .net's "Application_Start" and "Begin_Request" for java/tomcat/JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663511/event-like-nets-application-start-and-begin-request-for-java-tomcat-jsp)

The only problem is that the accepted answer doesn't answer how to do it. That makes sense: the question wasn't asking **how** to do it. The question was only asking **if** Java has an equivalent. Apparently it does - [but we won't tell you how.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3663614/12597)

## Research Effort

- [How to get request object from HttpSessionAttributeListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29069662/how-to-get-request-object-from-httpsessionattributelistener)
- [Event like .net's "Application_Start" and "Begin_Request" for java/tomcat/JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663511/event-like-nets-application-start-and-begin-request-for-java-tomcat-jsp)
- [ServletRequestListener Example Use Case](https://memorynotfound.com/servletrequestlistener-example-use-case/)
- [ServletRequestEvent and ServletRequestListener in Servlet](https://www.studytonight.com/servlet/servlet-request-event-and-listener.php)
- [The Java EE 5 Tutorial -  Handling Servlet Life-Cycle Events](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnafi.html)
- [Java Web series: Java Web basics and Java Web Basics](https://topic.alibabacloud.com/a/java-web-series-java-web-basics-and-java-web-basics_1_27_32644066.html)

I know that trying to figure out how to do it in JavaEE will take me at *least* 4 days. I'm hoping to cut that down to 6 or 7 hours by asking Stackoverflow.

This question took me an hour-and-a-half to write up. I wrote the ASP.net code, from memory, in 25 seconds. It took me longer to ask the question about how to do it in Java than it would have just taken me to do it in ASP.net - which shows just how crushed and defeated i am right now.

**Edit**: I happen to be using Java 8. I *assume* that corresponds to JavaEE 8.

Comment: You can annotate with `@WebListener`, and skip editing the web xml configuration file.

Comment: In regards to where you are stuck; add a method called requestDestroyed​ to your ExampleListenerForThisQuestion class and place some System.out.println()  lines  in order for you to see some output in console or log.

Comment: Java 8 is ok.  Are you using Tomcat?

Comment: @rickz Glassfish. Is the web-server an important issue here? Isn't it part of JavaEE/JakartaEE standard, which the web-server is required to implement?

Answer (score 1):

## `ServletRequestListener`

> i want to know when: when a request starts and when a request ends

Use a `ServletRequestListener` as suggested in your Question. This is a long-standing feature in the Servlet API, since Servlet spec version 2.4.

- [`requestInitialized`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/5.0/apidocs/jakarta/servlet/servletrequestlistener#requestInitialized(jakarta.servlet.ServletRequestEvent)) method is your hook to know when handling of a request begins.
- [`requestDestroyed`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/5.0/apidocs/jakarta/servlet/servletrequestlistener#requestDestroyed(jakarta.servlet.ServletRequestEvent)) method is your hook for when handling of a request ends.

### Example code

Here is a little demo I wrote.

```java
package work.basil.example.demo;

import jakarta.servlet.ServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletRequestEvent;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletRequestListener;
import jakarta.servlet.annotation.WebListener;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import java.time.Instant;

@WebListener
public class RequestAnnouncer implements ServletRequestListener
{
    @Override
    public void requestInitialized ( ServletRequestEvent sre )
    {
        ServletRequestListener.super.requestInitialized( sre );

        ServletRequest sr = sre.getServletRequest();
        HttpServletRequest request = ( HttpServletRequest ) sr;
        String url = request.getRequestURL() + ( request.getQueryString() == null ? "" : "?" + request.getQueryString() );
        System.out.println( "INFO - Request initialized in thread " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " at " + Instant.now() + " | " + url );
    }

    @Override
    public void requestDestroyed ( ServletRequestEvent sre )
    {
        ServletRequestListener.super.requestDestroyed( sre );

        ServletRequest sr = sre.getServletRequest();
        HttpServletRequest request = ( HttpServletRequest ) sr;
        String url = request.getRequestURL() + ( request.getQueryString() == null ? "" : "?" + request.getQueryString() );
        System.out.println( "INFO - Request destroyed in thread " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " at " + Instant.now() + " | " + url );
    }
}
```

#### `@WebListener`

Notice the annotation [`@WebListener`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/5.0/apidocs/jakarta/servlet/annotation/weblistener). With this annotation, you can skip editing the web XML configuration file. The `@WebListener` acts as a flag at runtime, so the Servlet container will automatically detect, instantiate, and execute this class at the appropriate point in the lifecycle of your web app. This modern convenience was added in Servlet spec 3.0.

#### `jakarta.*` package naming

Also notice the `jakarta.*` package naming in the `import` statements. Java EE is now known as Jakarta EE after Oracle Corp handed responsibility to the Eclipse Foundation a few years ago. Jakarta Servlet specifications versions 4 and 5 (used here) are equivalent except for a change in package names from javax.* to jakarta.*.

By the way, [Jakarta Servlet spec version 6](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/6.0/) was released this year as part of Jakarta EE 10, with the first major changes in many years. See article, [*Top 5 things to know about the Jakarta Servlet 6.0 API release*](https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/Top-5-things-to-know-about-the-Jakarta-Servlet-60-API-release).

### Run example

When run in the Microsoft Edge browser Version 103.0.1264.62 (Official build) (arm64) for macOS Monterey 12.4 on Apache Tomcat 2022.2 Beta with Adoptium Temurin for Java 18.0.1+10 on a MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2021) Apple M1 Pro, for URL `http://localhost:8080/demo_war_exploded/hello-servlet` results in the following output.

```
INFO - Request initialized in thread 23 at 2022-07-15T20:55:21.060303Z | http://localhost:8080/demo_war_exploded/hello-servlet
INFO - Request destroyed in thread 23 at 2022-07-15T20:55:21.066361Z | http://localhost:8080/demo_war_exploded/hello-servlet
INFO - Request initialized in thread 26 at 2022-07-15T20:55:21.151810Z | http://localhost:8080/demo_war_exploded/hello-servlet
INFO - Request destroyed in thread 26 at 2022-07-15T20:55:21.152086Z | http://localhost:8080/demo_war_exploded/hello-servlet
```

Why do we get a four lines instead of two for a single request? Well, looking at the access logs shows that this browser sent a request on both IPv4 and IPv6. And the browser sent a request to just `/`, but I have no idea why.

```
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Jul/2022:13:55:21 -0700] "GET /demo_war_exploded/hello-servlet HTTP/1.1" 200 306
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Jul/2022:13:55:21 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 683
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [15/Jul/2022:13:55:21 -0700] "GET /demo_war_exploded/hello-servlet HTTP/1.1" 200 306
```

## Filters

When to use `ServletRequestListener` and when to use filters? Filters are used in a chain to process the request and response. The listener fires once per request, at the very beginning and the very end. In contrast, multiple filters may fire for a single request. To quote the Javadoc:

> Interface for receiving notification events about requests coming into and going out of scope of a web application.
>
> A ServletRequest is defined as coming into scope of a web application when it is about to enter the first servlet or filter of the web application, and as going out of scope as it exits the last servlet or the first filter in the chain.

So we have a progression of beginning, middle, and end where the listener fires for beginning and end while zero, one , or more filters may fire in the middle.

> `ServletRequestListener#requestInitialized` > [ … filters … ] > `ServletRequestListener#requestDestroyed`

Interestingly, I noticed the *Filter* API was added in Servlet spec version 2.3, and the *ServletRequestListener* API was added in 2.4. So I would guess that soon after rolling out the filter feature, developers found a need for hooks that act as temporal bookends, bracketing outside a series of filters. Since any number of filters may fire, without one filter knowing about the others, you might want a hook for the very beginning and the very end.

---

## Servlet example code

If curious, the Servlet I wrote for the above example:

```java
package work.basil.example.demo;

import java.io.*;
import java.time.Instant;

import jakarta.servlet.http.*;
import jakarta.servlet.annotation.*;

@WebServlet ( name = "helloServlet", value = "/hello-servlet" )
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    private String message;

    public void init ( )
    {
        message = "What time is it?";
    }

    public void doGet ( HttpServletRequest request , HttpServletResponse response ) throws IOException
    {
        response.setContentType( "text/html" );

        // Hello
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println( "<!DOCTYPE html>" );
        out.println(
                """
                <head>
                  <meta charset="utf-8">
                  <title>Servlet Request Listener Example</title>
                  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">  -->
                  <!-- <script src="script.js"></script> -->
                </head>
                """
        );
        out.println( "<html lang='en'>" );
        out.println( "<body>" );
        out.println( "<h1>" + message + "</h1>" );
        out.println( "<p>" + Instant.now() + "</p>" );
        out.println( "</body>" );
        out.println( "</html>" );
    }

    public void destroy ( )
    {
    }
}
```

---

You said:

> I happen to be using Java 8. I assume that corresponds to JavaEE 8.

If you mean a correspondence between version numbers 8 and 8, no.

The name Java EE (now Jakarta EE), meaning “Enterprise Edition”, is a bit of a misnomer. Jakarta EE is just a bunch of specifications for a bunch of software that can be called from Java code running in a Java Virtual Machine. So "Java EE" was never really "Java", it was a framework of specs and libraries for helping developers build enterprise-oriented applications.

Java EE 8, re-released as [Jakarta EE 8](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/), [requires Java 8](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/platform-spec-8.html#container-requirements). (Major changes came to Java 9 through 11 that may cause problems when migrating.)

[Jakarta EE 9](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/9/) is essentially the same as Jakarta EE 8, but for the change in package naming from `javax.*` to `jakarta.*`. So it too [requires Java 8](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/9/jakarta-platform-spec-9.html#container-requirements).

[Jakarta EE 9.1](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/9.1/) is a revamp and cleanup of Jakarta EE 8 & 9, dropping some old deprecations, adding more deprecations, and doing other work to lay the foundation for future innovations. Among the changes is [requiring implementations to support Java 11](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/9.1/jakarta-platform-spec-9.1.html#changes-in-jakarta-ee-9-1) in [addition to Java 8](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/9.1/jakarta-platform-spec-9.1.html#container-requirements) (both [LTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long-term_support) versions). And while not an explicit requirement, all implementations are expected to be able to run in Java 17 (the current [LTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long-term_support) version) as well.

[Jakarta EE 10](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/10/) brings the first wave of those long-awaited innovations.

| Jakarta EE | Requires Java |
| --- | --- |
| 8 | 8 |
| 9 | 8 |
| 9.1 | 8 & 11 (and likely 17) |
| 10 | ?? |

Comment: How do you get ahold of the [**HttpServletResponse**](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html) from the [**ServletRequestEvent**](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequestEvent.html) passed in to [**requestDestroyed**](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequestListener.html#requestDestroyed(javax.servlet.ServletRequestEvent)) so i can inspect the **Status** (e.g. `429 Too Many Requests`)

Comment: @IanBoyd I do not know. I suggest you post another Question on that matter.

Comment: Fortunately i thought ahead, and added it to this question right off the bat.